# How to use add metadata / tags while uploading a file into azure blob storage container and use the same for filtering in blob trigger

Tags: azure, tags, metadata, azure-blob-trigger

How to use add metadata / tags while uploading a file into azure blob storage container and use the same for filtering in blob trigger (Path)

Eg. I want to pick files with a specific metadata / tag (DocType=RequiresScan)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details like which SDK you're using, the code you have written so far and the issues you're running into.